# Intellij IDEA removing unused import statements on build

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After building an Intellij project, import statements that are not in use are automatically removed. How do I disable this feature? The include statements are removed *after* building, not before building the project. The setting "Optimize Imports on the fly " is not what I am looking for.

Comment: why would you have to disable that? why do you want to keep not used imports?

Comment: When I'm debugging a project, if certain parts of the code is commented out, some include statements are then removed. So after I uncomment these codes, the include statements may need to be readded into the code. But most importantly: its causing me extreme frustration not having full control over the coding process.

Comment: @matt, yes, I'm referring to import statements, have corrected the original post. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.2 x64

Comment: The code is optimized on the build, you are not getting an unused code in debugging, as it is not present in the compiled file. You cannot modify the code on the fly during execution because JVM copies the executable and does not allow you to change it.

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi Im not concerned about the compiled file, rather, after building the project, the import statements simply get deleted from the editor in the IDE.

Comment: You can check this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-auto-import.html with some more info on those settings for all languages

Comment: You should probably create an example. Start a new project, create a main class with an unused import, then show that it was removed. You might need to include a screenshot of your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Disable **Optimize imports on the fly** option:
[image]

Comment: Please read question carefully before posting answer